# Compile VB6 program to Native or POSIX application?

Tags: vb6, compilation, linker, subsystem

Lately I was experimenting on my old VB6, and found there a strange thing.
Using ProcMon I found that while compiling, VB6 runs Link.exe with parameters like this:
`LINK "D:\Folder\Form1.OBJ" "D:\Folder\Project1.OBJ"... /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,4.0 ...`
I wrote `Link.exe /?` in cmd and found there

```
link.exe /?
usage: LINK [options] [files] [@commandfile]      
    options:      
    ...    
    /SUBSYSTEM:{NATIVE|WINDOWS|CONSOLE|WINDOWSCE|POSIX}
```

By default VB6 compiles with parameter /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.
But can I compile my VB6 code to Native or POSIX subsystem application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just sets a bit in the resultung exe file. Visual Basic uses Microsoft's standard linker which is also used for C/C++, that's why the flag is there.

So yes, you can compile it with those settings, but I'm certain that the resulting exe won't run in native mode or in the Posix subsystem.

For more information on those settings you might want to check out information about the PE file format and have a look at the DUMPBIN and EDITBIN tools.

Answer (score 2):

VB applications uses Win32 calls, so there is no chance your application will work, even if you uses a console-only application.

Comment: You can [write a console application in VB6](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/), but it will still require Windows.

Comment: Yes. Also there's a very easy way to create it(or just convert it). Look here http://www.nirsoft.net/vb/appmodechange.html

Answer (score 0):

Console is the only alternative subsystem that is useful.  Posix isn't even present since Win2K and Native is for kernel mode drivers.

If any of this is news to you, I wonder why you are playing with ProcMon?  Scary.

Comment: +1 for your first paragraph, but -1 for sounding like a jerk in the second.

Comment: 1) POSIX is alive in WinXP. Just google it and you'll find a lot about POSIX in XP. 2)I've used VB6 many-many years (~5 years), but i've never run Link.exe from cmd. 3)I'm using ProcMon, not just playing... Please, be more respectful when you're writtin' an answer.

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308259  I'm waiting to see a VB6 program that runs in the Posix *or* Interix subsystems.